# Limit random returned id's, but with unknown row count per id

Tags: php, mysql, random, row, limit

I want to select 5 random users out of my database and show all their food preferences.

Currently I have these tables:

```
CUSTOMERS
customer_id email 

FOOD_PREFERENCE
food_id food_name allergic_info

LISTING
customer_id food_id
```

My query has to be something similar to this:

```
SELECT c.email, f.food_name, f.allergic_info
FROM customers c, food_preference f, listing l
WHERE l.customer_id=c.customer_id AND f.food_id=l.food_id
ORDER BY rand(c.customer_id) LIMIT 10
```

The problem is: I don't want to limit the rows that are returned, I just want to limit the different customer_id's.
Buts since I have to select them randomly, I can't use math (like e.g. "WHERE customer_id < 6").
Is there a way to randomly select 5 customers and return all their food_preferences within the same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

So, your query should be:

```
SELECT c.email, f.food_name, f.allergic_info
FROM listing l JOIN
     customers c  
     ON l.customer_id = c.customer_id JOIN
     food_preference f
     ON f.food_id = l.food_id
ORDER BY rand(c.customer_id)  -- I don't know why you are providing a see here
LIMIT 10;
```

If all customers have food preferences, just put the `limit` in a subquery:

```
SELECT c.email, f.food_name, f.allergic_info
FROM listing l JOIN
     (SELECT c.*
      FROM customers c  
      ORDER BY rand()
      LIMIT 5
     ) c
     ON l.customer_id = c.customer_id JOIN
     food_preference f
     ON f.food_id = l.food_id;
```

If not all customers are in `listing` and you only want customers in `listing`, then you can add another `join`:

```
SELECT c.email, f.food_name, f.allergic_info
FROM listing l JOIN
     customers c
     ON l.customer_id = c.customer_id JOIN
     food_preference f
     ON f.food_id = l.food_id JOIN
     (SELECT customer_id
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id FROM LISTING) lc
      ORDER BY rand()
      LIMIT 5
     ) lc
     ON l.customer_id = lc.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the customer in subquery and *then* do the JOINs.

Also, it's recommended to use the modern explicit JOIN syntax.

```
select c.email,
    f.food_name,
    f.allergic_info
from listing l
join (
    select *
    from customers
    order by rand() limit 10
    ) c on l.customer_id = c.customer_id
join food_preference f on f.food_id = l.food_id;
```